# Same Model, different Templates (and Actions) in extbase extension

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I don't know if I've set up my extension a little quirky.

I have one model, but two plugins, as I would like to display the same data in different ways.

What thought I'd do: assign pi1 and pi2 two different Fluid templates, where all the display logic is done. But as far as I understood now, there is no such switch, due to "Convention over configuration", I need a separate controller for pi2, right?

Now I have this in ext_tables.php:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'STUBR.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Pi1',
    array(
        'Institution' => 'list, show',

    ),
    // non-cacheable actions
    array(
        'Institution' => '',

    )
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'STUBR.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Pi2',
    array(
        'Institution' => 'list, show',

    ),
    // non-cacheable actions
    array(
        'Institution' => '',

    )
);
```

Do I really have to adapt everything by re-naming "Institution" here, in the Controller(s) and in the template directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question you asked in your answer ... it is possible to configure the TypoScript of your Extension on a per plugin base. Just add the pluginname with a leading underscore to your TS key like this

```
plugin.tx_stellen_pi2 {
    settings {
       displaymode = 1
    }
}
```

Instead of using a if condition you could also set a different TemplateRootPath so another template would be rendered for pi2.

Comment: Ah, thanks! And is there a way to access Partials from the 1st template if you set the TemplateRootPath?

Comment: If you dont overwrite your partialRootPath your templates will use the same templates. You can also define multiple paths to look for layouts, partials or templates with partialRootPaths.10, partialRootPaths.20 etc

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you can set the displayMode in a FlexForm. Every FlexForm property prefixed with `settings.` will be available in the `{settings}` array. Just configure the FlexForm in `ext_tables.php`:

```
$pluginSignature = str_replace('_','',$_EXTKEY) . '_pi1';
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_addlist'][$pluginSignature] = 'pi_flexform';
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPiFlexFormValue($pluginSignature, 'FILE:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Configuration/FlexForm/flexform_pi1.xml');
```

Then add the FlexForm XML to the path configured:

```
<T3DataStructure>
    <meta>
        <langDisable>1</langDisable>
    </meta>
    <sheets>
        <sDEF>
            <ROOT>
                <TCEforms>
                    <sheetTitle>Configuration</sheetTitle>
                </TCEforms>
                <type>array</type>
                <el>
                    <settings.displayMode>
                        <TCEforms>
                            <exclude>0</exclude>
                            <label>Display mode</label>
                            <config>
                                <type>select</type>
                                <items type="array">
                                    <numIndex index="0" type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0">Neat</numIndex>
                                        <numIndex index="1">1</numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
                                    <numIndex index="1" type="array">
                                        <numIndex index="0">Clean</numIndex>
                                        <numIndex index="1">2</numIndex>
                                    </numIndex>
                                </items>
                                <minitems>0</minitems>
                                <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                                <size>1</size>
                            </config>
                        </TCEforms>
                    </settings.displayMode>
                </el>
            </ROOT>
        </sDEF>
    </sheets>
</T3DataStructure>
```

In this example, a select box with two options "neat" and "clean" is added.

You can then use this in your Fluid template (you could also use the SwitchViewHelper instead of the if construct if you have more than two modes):

```
<f:if condition="{settings.displayMode} == 1">
    <f:then>
        <f:render partial="Neat/List" arguments="{_all}" />
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        <f:render partial="Clean/List" arguments="{_all}" />
    </f:else
</f:if>
```

Remember that you can nest partials, so it's no problem to have a partial in a partial in a partial. So just use a partial for each view.

If you want to have it less hackish-looking, you could give the display mode a speaking value:

```
<numIndex index="0" type="array">
    <numIndex index="0">Neat</numIndex>
    <numIndex index="1">Neat</numIndex>
</numIndex>
<numIndex index="1" type="array">
    <numIndex index="0">Clean</numIndex>
    <numIndex index="1">Clean</numIndex>
</numIndex>
```

Then you can use this to call the partial like this

```
<f:render partial="List/{settings.displayMode}" arguments="{_all}" />
```

and get rid of the if construct that way.

Comment: Lorenz, thanks for another great tutorial! If you write an extbase book, I'll buy it unseen

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it this way now. Keep one controller, just fork the template by setting some page TS on the page the plugin is on.

```
plugin.tx_stellen {
    settings {
       displaymode = 1
    }
}
```

and then `<f:if condition="{settings.displaymode}==1"></f:if>`

This is workaroundish, though, as it is valid for the entire page (and I wouldn't even need the three different plugins at all). Isn't it possible to define TypoScript "per Plugin" directly in the extension?

Comment: Defining TypoScript "per plugin" isn't possible because page content is rendered through TypoScript too, i.e. you can never target a single content element by TypoScript. Some piBase extensions had own FlexForm fields that allowed overriding the TypoScript but I've never seen an Extbase extension implementing this. But there are still conditions (as you mentioned) and FlexForm (see my answer).